# mongoDB does not combine 1d and 2d indexes, geo queries scans all documents irrespective of filters applied to limit the number of records

Tags: mongodb, indexing, 2d

Below is the output from explain for one of the queries:

```
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : **199564**,
    "nscanned" : 199564,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : **199564**,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : **199564**,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1234,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "MongoDB",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

This query scans all the **199564** records, where as constrains applied in the filter for the query, which should be around few hundred records only.

Pointers would be much appreciated

Adding the query and indexes applied:

**Query**

> { 
>          "isfeatured" : 1 , 
>          "status" : 1 , 
>          "isfesturedseq" : 1 , 
>          "loc_long_lat" : { 
>              "$near" : [ 76.966438 , 11.114906]
>          } , 
>          "city_id" : "40" , 
>          "showTime.0" : { "$exists" : true}}

**Indexes**

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc_long_lat" : "2d"
    },
    "name" : "loc_long_lat_2d",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "georand" : "2d"
    },
    "name" : "georand_2d",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "city_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "city_id_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "endDatetime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "endDatetime_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "movieid" : 1
    },
    "name" : "movieid_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "theaterid" : 1
    },
    "name" : "theaterid_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "status" : 1
    },
    "name" : "status_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "isfeatured" : 1
    },
    "name" : "isfeatured_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "isfesturedseq" : 1
    },
    "name" : "isfesturedseq_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "is_popular" : 1
    },
    "name" : "is_popular_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc_name" : 1
    },
    "name" : "loc_name_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "est_city_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "est_city_id_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "isfeatured" : 1,
        "status" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "isfeatured_1_status_1_city_id_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map",
    "background" : true
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "movieid" : 1,
        "endDatetime" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1,
        "status" : 1
    },
    "name" : "movieid_1_endDatetime_1_city_id_1_status_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map",
    "background" : 2
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "movieid" : 1,
        "endDatetime" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1,
        "status" : 1,
        "georand" : 1
    },
    "name" : "movieid_1_endDatetime_1_city_id_1_status_1_georand_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map",
    "background" : 2
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "rand" : 1
    },
    "name" : "rand_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "isfeatured" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1,
        "status" : 1
    },
    "name" : "isfeatured_1_city_id_1_status_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "movieid" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "movieid_1_city_id_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc_long_lat" : 1,
        "is_popular" : 1,
        "movieid" : 1,
        "status" : 1
    },
    "name" : "loc_long_lat_1_is_popular_1_movieid_1_status_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "status" : 1,
        "city_id" : 1,
        "theaterid" : 1,
        "endDatetime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "status_1_city_id_1_theaterid_1_endDatetime_1",
    "ns" : "test_live.movies_theater_map",
    "background" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$near` operator uses a 2d or 2dsphere index to return documents in order from nearest to furthest. For a 2d index, a max of 100 documents are returned. Your query scanned every document because there were no matching documents and every document, from nearest to furthest, had to be scanned to check if it matched all the conditions.

I would suggest the following to improve the query:

1. Use the `$maxDistance` option, which is specified in radians for legacy coordinates, to limit the maximum number of documents scanned.
2. Use a 2dsphere index, ideally with GeoJSON points instead of legacy coordinates. You can have compound indexes with prefix keys to a geo index with a 2dsphere index, so you could index the query in part on all the other conditions to reduce the number of documents that need to be scanned. What version of MongoDB are you using? You may not have all of these features available with an old version.
3. Use `limit` to limit the maximum number of documents scanned. However, when the query has less results than the value of `limit`, you'll still scan every document.